# is possible to have ng-include inside option element?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change template of option on the fly for a select element. Here is what I am trying to do, I have select option, which will allow user to select what kind of information they want to see when selecting a student. If the user chose 'Basic' then I show only Id and Name properties of Student class. If the user chooses 'Detail' then I show, Id, Name and Grade. The current implementation is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="Basic">
        <select ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="student in Students">
           {{student.Id}} - {{student.Name}}
        </option>
        </select>
    </script>
     <script type="text/ng-template" id="Detail">
        <select ng-model="selectedItem">
        <option ng-repeat="student in Students">
           {{student.Id}} - {{student.Name}} -- {{student.Grade}}
        </option>
        </select>
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="TemplateCtrl">
            Details Level: <select ng-model="detailLevel" ng-options="c.Id for c in Details"></select>
            <div ng-include="detailLevel.Id"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/TemplateCtrl.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I am duplicating the code in both the ng-template 'Basic' and 'Detail'. Initially I was trying something like the following

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="Basic">
           {{student.Id}} - {{student.Name}}
    </script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="Detail">
           {{student.Id}} - {{student.Name}} -- {{student.Grade}}
    </script>
```

but when I try to do ng-include in side  tag, browsers did not like.  I might be missing something simple here, what I am doing wrong to create the duplicate code smell here?
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try using the [ng-switch directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch), instead of templates. 
Then the following should work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="TemplateCtrl">
            Details Level: <select ng-model="detailLevel" ng-options="c.Id for c in Details"></select>
            <div ng-switch="detailLevel">
                <div ng-switch-when="Basic">
                    <select ng-model="selectedItem">
                        <option ng-repeat="student in Students">{{student.Id}} - {{student.Name}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div ng-switch-when="Detail">
                    <select ng-model="selectedItem">
                        <option ng-repeat="student in Students">{{student.Id}} - {{student.Name}} -- {{student.Grade}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/TemplateCtrl.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Franquis, yes ng-switch will work but it is not modular approach as I was thinking.

Comment: I take it no other way to do this, so I am accepting this as answer.